HTML opening with VS Code Live Server buth not from my local files
I have an issue with this HTML code using d3.js. It's working fine as long as I open it with Live Server on VS Code, but once I open it from my local files it doesn't show the graphs it creates, I was wondering what could I do to fix it.
Here's the code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Proyecto II</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .bar {
            fill: url(#gradient);
            stroke: #fff;
        }
        .label {
            font-size: 10px;
            text-anchor: middle;
        }
        .center-label {
            font-size: 14px;
            text-anchor: middle;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .legend {
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        .legend rect {
            stroke: none;
        }
        .legend text {
            fill: #000;
            font-weight: bold;
            alignment-baseline: middle;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sundown Chart</h1>
    <p>Shows population of each city</p>
    <div id="chart2"></div>
    <div id="chart1"></div>

<script>
    const dataUrl = "./files/distritos.csv";

    d3.csv(dataUrl).then(function(data) {
        data.forEach(d => {
            d.POPULATION = +d.POPULATION;
        });

        const width = 800;
        const height = 400;
        const radius = Math.min(width, height * 2) / 2;

        const groupedData = d3.group(data, d => d.ID.split('.')[0]);

        const colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .domain(groupedData.keys())
            .range(d3.schemeCategory10);

        const radialScale = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, d => d.POPULATION)])
            .range([0, radius]);

        const arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(0)
            .outerRadius(d => radialScale(d.data.POPULATION));

        const pie = d3.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(d => d.POPULATION)
            .startAngle(-Math.PI / 2)
            .endAngle(Math.PI / 2);

        const svg1 = d3.select("#chart1").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height + 50);

        const g1 = svg1.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height})`);

        const gArcs1 = g1.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        gArcs1.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", d => colorScale(d.data.ID.split('.')[0]));

        gArcs1.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                const [x, y] = arc.centroid(d);
                const midAngle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
                const offset = midAngle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1;
                return `translate(${x * 1.1 * offset}, ${y * 1.1 * offset})`;
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(d => d.data.CITY);

        const svg2 = d3.select("#chart2").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height + 50);

        const g2 = svg2.append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2}, ${height})`);

        const gArcs2 = g2.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        gArcs2.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc);

        gArcs2.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                const [x, y] = arc.centroid(d);
                const midAngle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
                const offset = midAngle < Math.PI ? 1 : -1;
                return `translate(${x * 1.1 * offset}, ${y * 1.1 * offset})`;
            })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .text(d => d.data.CITY);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>

Already tried adding the ./ before the path of the .csv I'm using to get the data from, but it hasn't worked so far.

Download https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js and reference it locally. This still may not work. The problem with trying to load data using file:// urls is that modern browsers restrict them more than web-based urls in order to help mitigate security issues.

I didn't really think of that, I'm fairly new to HTML, I'll give it a try, thank you!
